# Counting class occurrences within a parent element

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to delete rows from a table with the additional check that a user must not be able to delete the last row in the table.

I have a table which is set up similar to this:

```
<table id="columns" class="dynamicadd">
    <thead><tr>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Show</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select name="colperiod[]"><!-- options --></select></td>
            <td><select name="colresult[]"><!-- options --></select></td>
            <td><select name="colshow[]"><!-- options --></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="#">X</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a second table with a very similar structure, different ID, on the same page:

```
<table id="aggregate" class="dynamicadd">
    <thead><tr>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Show</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select name="acolperiod[]"><!-- options --></select></td>
            <td><select name="acolresult[]"><!-- options --></select></td>
            <td><select name="acolshow[]"><!-- options --></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="#">X</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I then have some javascript for cloning rows: which is working.

I am interested in having a single row removing function that can work across the tables. If I need to add a new table, I'd like to be able to do so without having to add JavaScript. I can get this working if I use different classes for the "delete" option. However, this is my attempt at a single function that can delete rows from either table:

```
$(document).on ('click', '.delete', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // count the number of rows in the current table
    var delCount = $(this).closest('table').children ('.delete').length;
    console.log (delCount); // 0 ??
    if (delCount > 1)
    {
        $(this).closest ('tr').remove();
    }
    else
    {
        // don't delete the last row.
        $(this).effect ("shake", {distance: 5});
    }
});
```

The variable `delCount` is 0, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less complicated and more efficient to just check if the row  has any siblings within the `<tbody>`;

```
$(document).on ('click', '.delete', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $btn = $(this),// cache `$(this)` to avoid calling it more than once
        $row = $btn.closest('tr');

    if ($row.siblings().length)
    {
        $row.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        $btn.effect ("shake", {distance: 5});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In writing this question, I did some "accidental learning".

`.children` should be `.find`:

```
$(document).on ('click', '.delete', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // count the number of rows in the current table
    var delCount = $(this).closest('table').find ('.delete').length;
    console.log (delCount);
    if (delCount > 1)
    {
        $(this).closest ('tr').remove();
    }
    else
    {
        // don't delete the last row.
        $(this).effect ("shake", {distance: 5});
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

For an explanation on how `.children` and `.find` differ, I found [this explanation by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/) which helped. **tl;dr**: `.children` looks one level down, `.find` does a full search of any child, grandchild, great... elements

Comment: wow in just 0 second you got the solution.how's that possible?

Comment: also what is the big diff between two selector

Comment: @AlivetoDie answering your own question is perfectly acceptable, although I would suggest to the OP that they actually explain ***why*** this works so that future viewers to the question find some value here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if he got an answer before asking the question then why he asked?

Comment: true, he did it really fast judging from the times both were posted :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie - when you ask a question, you are given the option to answer it and share what you've learned. That's what I did...

Comment: @Philip  oh you are so generous.I have no issue BTW, but i am not going to encourage it.Thanks.leaving now

Comment: @Philip what is the reason why children is suited in this example than find ? you should put  that in the answer since i think both work just like the same :)